# CSS Refuses to Update

Tags: php, css, caching, vagrant, laravel-5

**Environment Information**

- Framework: Laravel 5
- Application Environment: Vagrant, Virtual Box
- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
- Browser: Chrome

**What's Happening:**

CSS will not update after the initial page load.  My vagrant environment uses a file share, and I have validated that the CSS changes are updating upon performing a save; but the page still renders outdated CSS.

I have performed all of the common cache clearing techniques manually, and have used the "Clear Cache" Chrome extension.

**The Question(s)**

It's behaving as though Vagrant / Virtual Box have their own caching mechanism, and that is somehow interfering with my updates. If that exists, is there a way to turn it off?

Does the Laravel 5 File cache driver house, or use, cached data outside of the `storage/` directory?

**What I've Done**

1. [Failure] Performed Hard Refresh
2. [Failure] Cleared Browser Cache
3. [Failure] Deleted the view, session and cache files located at: *storage/framework/*
4. [Failure] Added a Cache buster: `{{ asset('main.css').date('?ts=His')`
5. [Failure] Used Laravels artisan clear cache: `php artisan cache:clear`
6. [Works for initial load] `vagrant halt` / `vagrant up`
7. [Works for initial load] Rebooted machine

**Examples**

[image: Altered CSS]
[image: CSS on File Share]
[image: Rendered CSS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has actually been noticed before, and addressed in this [Google Forum conversation.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/7RgBxo6EksQ) It is a failure of the `sendfile()` syscall within the web server daemon, as something is broken in Virtualbox.

The TL;DR version is that you need to add `EnableSendfile off` to Apache or `sendfile off;` for nginx.

After that, you should be golden.